# Run "Login Items" at OSX boot, but keep session locked

Tags: macos, mac

Is there any way to, at boot-up, cause OSX to run the "Login Items" for a given user, while keeping your session locked?

My goal is to have my user completely loaded (in particular, VMWare vms) without having to touch the system after turning on the power or rebooting. That said, I also don't want the computer in a usable state by rebooting without the account password.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.  An easily defeatable launchagent that locked the screen via Fast User Switching would be one option, but again, not very secure.  You could set launchagents at the system level that launch VMs, and run them under your user, but I don't think that would give you the desired affect (not sure how Fusion's console would treat them).  might be worth testing and playing with though.